# How to use getnameinfo instead of gethostbyname?

Tags: c++, sockets, gcc, warnings, cross-compiling

in code :

```
if ((host = (struct hostent*) gethostbyname(address) ) == 0) // address is a string
```

I've got warning when cross compiling (generic arm architecture) on 4.5.x gcc :

```
(.text+0x1558): warning: gethostbyname is obsolescent, use getnameinfo() instead.
```

[getnameinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is:

```
int WSAAPI getnameinfo(
  __in   const struct sockaddr FAR *sa,
  __in   socklen_t salen,
  __out  char FAR *host,
  __in   DWORD hostlen,
  __out  char FAR *serv,
  __in   DWORD servlen,
  __in   int flags
);
```

And it got more parameters... And I'm confused with it, I just need it work as gethostbyname were working. What parameter to pass to keep it simple stupid as it was with gethostbyname?

Finally here is my try:

```
struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
struct hostent *host;        /* Structure containing host information */

/* open socket */
if ((handle = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
    return LILI_ERROR;

memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
servAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address.ptr());
servAddr.sin_port        = htons(port);

char servInfo[NI_MAXSERV];
if ( ( host = (hostent*) getnameinfo(
                 (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr
                 ,sizeof (struct sockaddr)
                 ,address.ptr(), address.size()
                 ,servInfo, NI_MAXSERV
                 ,NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV )  ) == 0)
    return LILI_ERROR;

if (::connect(handle, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
    return LILI_ERROR;
```

It compiles well and no segmentation fault on start up but I can't connect my server with it :(

Comment: As you marked the question with [tag:c++], I'd suggest using [boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: Thank you. but yet I don't want to touch boost. But I think there is no reason to not use boost, so I think I will take a look.

Comment: You are using the return value, assuming it holds the hostname, but this is not correct. I've made an edit to my answer addressing this issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`gethostbyname()` does a name→IP lookup. It should be replaced with **`getaddrinfo()`**, which can do the same.

**This means the warning is completely wrong.** getnameinfo() is the replacement of gethostbyaddr(), both for IP→name lookups. The reverse.

name→IP: `gethostbyname()`, `getaddrinfo()`
IP→name: `gethostbyaddr()`, `getnameinfo()`

The newer functions can do more: they handle IPv6 *and* can translate strings like 'http' to 80 (port). In the future they can also determine if e.g. TCP should be used for the service in question or SCTP. The interface is ready.

Answer (score 12):

Beej's explains it pretty good. [`gethostbyname()`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html) does not works well with IPV6 and thus you should use [`getnameinfo()`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getnameinfoman.html) instead. All you have to do is to fill in the required informations, i.e.

```c
getnameinfo(
    &sa,             // Pointer to your struct sockaddr
    sizeof sa,       // Size of this struct
    host,            // Pointer to hostname string
    sizeof host,     // Hostname string buffer length
    service,         // Pointer to service name string
    sizeof service,  // Service name string buffer length
    0                // No flags given
);
```

**Edit**: After some research, I've found that

```c
getnameinfo(&sa, sizeof(sa), hostname, size_hostname, NULL, 0, 0);
```

should be sufficient.

**Edit #2** I've noticed you are trying to use the return value of `getnameinfo` as hostname. But that is not correct, the hostname is saved within the provided `host` pointer. The return value indicates whether the operation was sufficient. Also have a look at [the man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getnameinfo.3.html).

Comment: If you're printing the informations of your host, i.e. of `*host` and of `*service`, are you getting the correct content within the strings?

Comment: it were working just fine with gethostbyname, and yet I can't catch the bug here.

Comment: but it's getaddrinfo example and I'm trying to use getnameinfo.

Comment: Right, but as mentioned on the site you can also perform hostname lookups with `getaddrinfo`.